# How to set a default value for AngularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```html
    <li ng-repeat="item in quantityList track by $index" ng-model="isPageValid='true'">

    <input value="item.quantity" ng-blur="validateQuantity(item)" ng-model="item.quantity">

    </li>
```

I'm trying to set a default value for a status variable each time an ng-repeat loop occurs.  I've tried ng-model, but that doesn't work.  For instance,

1. I'd like to set *isPageValid*="true" before each time the ng-repeat loop runs.  'True' is will be the default value, and the validation function will test whether *isPageValid* should be set to 'false'.
2. I'd like the ng-repeat loop to run each time the ng-blur is exercised.

NOTE: I understand the way I'm using ng-model is incorrect, but this is just to illustrate the issue.

HTML:

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in quantityList track by $index" ng-model="isPageValid='true'">

    <input value="item.quantity" ng-blur="validateQuantity(item)" ng-model="item.quantity">

</li>
```

JS:

```js
scope.validateQuantity = function(item){
    var qty = item.quantity;

    if(parseInt(qty) >=1 && parseInt(qty) <= 200){
          item.isQuantityValid = true;
     }else{
           item.isQuantityValid = false;
           scope.isPageValid = false;
     }
}
```

The loop creates a list of input boxes.  The objective is to create a global validation value called *isPageValid* which is 'false' if the validation by the JS fails for any input box.  Note, when ng-blur is exercised, the JS validation runs and loop should re-run.

Comment: The HTML code posted incorrectly.  Here it is:

Comment: <li ng-repeat="item in quantityList track by $index" ng-model="isPageValid='true'">

Comment: <input value="item.quantity" ng-blur="validateQuantity(item)" ng-model="item.quantity">

</li>

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: Is it a good candidate for creating filter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) could help...

```
<ul ng-init="isPageValid='true'">
  <li ng-repeat="item in quantityList track by $index" >
    <input ng-blur="validateQuantity(item)" ng-model="item.quantity">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that it would be better practice to initialise `isPageValid` in the controller that is in the same scope as your `validateQuantity` function.

Comment: Thanks Miller.  I tried that but it seemed to set isPageValid to be a constant.

Comment: I've updated my answer... the ng-init should be outside the ng-repeat as ng-repeat creates a new scope for each item

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could initialise `isPageValid` in your controller and update the value after each call to `validateQuantity`...

In your controller:

```
scope.isPageValid = true;

function updatePageValid() {
  scope.isPageValid = scope.quantityList.every(item => item.isQuantityValid);
}

scope.validateQuantity = function(item) {
    var qty = parseInt(item.quantity);
    item.isQuantityValid = (qty >= 1 && qty <= 200);
    updatePageValid();
});
```

Comment: Great! I think this does it. Thanks Miller.